# Create a page with user credentials from PHP form

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create a page with php and put in text from form.

Here's what i know:

- I know some php and how to write content to a database
- I know how to create form in html
- I need to send text from form `createUserProfiles.php` to `/u/username.php` using templates like `/templates/profile-templates.php`.

**side note:** i know how to create a page but i dont know how to write php code in it or use a template to create user profile. and i tried googling it but i didn't find anything that answered my question.

Comment: There are many many "getting started" guides about the first steps in using php on the internet. None of those helped? Sorry, but the purpose of this site is to help people with _specific_ questions in their code. This question is too broad, it basically asks: "tell me everything about programming, the web and how I can start learning all that". It is impossible to answer to that in a place like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

createUserProfiles.php

```
<form method="post" action="u/username.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create User">
</form>
```

Now we will submit the data to database and will present these submitted values to `u/username.php` by loading the template `templates/profile-templates.php` inside it.

```
<?php
//connect to db
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
//feed the values from previous form to db
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(username,email) VALUES(:uname,:email)");
$stmt->execute(array(':uname' => $_POST['username'], ':email' => $_POST['email']));
//now make an array with key name and its values
$attribute = array ('{user_name}'=>$_POST['username'], '{email}'=>$_POST['email']);
//load the template into a variable called $html
$html = file_get_contents ('templates/profile-templates.php');
//Now replace {user_name} and {email} present in template file with real data fetched from user.
foreach($attribute as $key => $value){
$html = str_replace ("{$key}", $value, $html);}
//At last echo the variable
echo $html;
```

Just make sure that the template file has curly brackets within which the data will be placed via PHP.
[reference](http://web4code.blogspot.in/2015/07/fetch-template-to-display-submitted-form.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your method is hard you should use a sql server as data types and storage function are easy to use. Follow howCodes tutorials on creating a social network it will give you a basic idea of html forms and php